# Fluxbox menu entry that prompts for some input

Tags: bash, x11, fluxbox, dialog

How do I ask 'which man file would you like to open?' in one command from the commandline, which will also open `xterm` at the same time. This is needed for a fluxbox menu item.

For it to be a fluxbox menu item, it must fulfil this format

```
[exec] (Which man page do you want to read?) {read -p 'which man file would you like to open? '; xterm -e man "$REPLY"}
```

where

- `[exec]` - look out its an executable command
- `(Question)` - title
- `{xterm -e man tmux}` - command with this syntax

Comment: Are you saying you want the command to also open another instance of `xterm`?

Comment: yes, but where it opens a man page that you've just chosen

Answer (score 3):

You can open a `man` page in an `xterm` window using the following command:

```
$ xterm -e "man xterm"
```

This will results in the man page for `xterm` being opened in its own window.

[image: ss of man page in xterm]

If you'd like to make it a single command that will do this you could create an alias like so:

```
$ alias gman='xterm -e man \!$'
```

And then use it like this:

```
$ gman xterm
```

#### Prompting for a man page

You could use the GUI toolkit `zenity` to open a dialog box asking for a man page to be typed in, then take what was typed in and use the above method to open the respective man page.

```
$ zenity --entry --text "Enter man page name:"
```

Resulting in this dialog being displayed:

[image: ss of zenity dialog]

#### A complete example

Putting the above together you could do something like this:

```
$ xterm -e man $(zenity --entry --text "Enter man page name:")
```

[image: ss of zenity + xterm]

Answer (score 3):

This will prompt for a manpage and open it in `xterm`:

```
read -p 'which man file would you like to open? '
xterm -e man "$REPLY"
```

---

This will run the prompt in a new instance of `xterm`:

```
xterm -e sh -c 'read -p "which man file would you like to open? " && man "$REPLY"'
```

Comment: For it to be a fluxbox menu item, it must fulfil this format - [exec] (Which man page do you want to read?) {read -p 'which man file would you like to open? '; xterm -e man "$REPLY"} where [exec] = [look out its an executable command], (Question) = [title], and {xterm -e man tmux} = [command with this syntax] And unfortunately I cant massage this to work in the menu item

Comment: @user205787: Could you please [add that to your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/84761/edit)? Newlines are stripped from comments.

Comment: @user205787: I have edited my answer to include another possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately the second reply just creates a second instance of xterm with 'sh' in its title bar and showing the terminals border but nothing else. The innards are completely blank and see-through! I've tried using other terminals but none of them work. I've also tried running it from the cli, and the xterm window appears and then, quick as a flash, it disappears again. It stays just long enough for the brain to register it before disappearing again.

Comment: @user205787: What shell do you use?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu), urxvt, xterm, termit,eterm.